# Can't sync fullCalendar with Google calendar. I've looked everywhere, can't find what's wrong

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar

I have kept the original files and folder structure this time,
Simply changed the code from the 'default.html' to display the events from google calendar. But as soon as I add that script, It doesn't display the calendar or the events.

I'm really lost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='../fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='../fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                googleCalendarApiKey: 'MY KEY',
                events: {
                    googleCalendarId: 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/ID%group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics'
                }

            });
        });


    </script>
    <style>

        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id='calendar'></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `gcal.js` script that's required.

You need to include the following reference (after your fullCalendar.js):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
```

This file is included in the fullCalendar distribution.

See the full instructions for setting up fullCalendar with Google here - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/ - make sure you've set all the permissions on your calendar correctly as well at the Google side.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting a script error.  Press f12 in chrome and try again.  You will probably see more about the issue.